# I don't understand why it's looking for an ID instead of a view

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, handlebars.js

I'm trying to get a to a certain route, which contains a form, but for some reason it is looking for an id. I'm going to share my routes, my views and the error.

```
//celebrities routes 

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Celeb = require('../model/celebrity.model')

router.get('/celebrities', (req, res) => {
    Celeb.find()
        .then(AlltheModels => {
            console.log(AlltheModels)
            res.render('celebrities/index', { celebs: AlltheModels })
        })
        .catch(error => console.log('error while getting the celebrities', error))
})

router.get('/celebrities/:id', (req, res) => {
    const celebId = req.params.id
    console.log(celebId)
    Celeb.findById(celebId)

        .then(OneCeleb => {
            console.log(OneCeleb)
            res.render('celebrities/show', { celebOne: OneCeleb })
        })

        .catch(error => console.log('there was an error by retrieving..', error))
})

//NEW celebrities

router.get('/celebrities/new', (req, res) => {

    res.render('celebrities/new')
})

router.post('/celebrities', (req, res) => {
    const { name, occupation, catchPhrase } = req.body;
    Celeb.create({ name, occupation, catchPhrase })
        // .then(CelebNew => {
        //      CelebNew.save()
        //  console.log(CelebNew + '...has been entered')
        // })
        .then(() => res.redirect('/celebrities'))
        .catch(error => `There was an error of ${error}`, err)
})

module.exports = router;
```

Here's the view that should lead to the form view

```
<div>
    <a href="/celebrities/new">Create a new Celebrity</a>
</div>


<div>
    {{#each celebs}}
    <a href="/celebrities/{{_id}}">
        <h2>{{this.name}}</h2>
    </a>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

and here's the error

"GET /celebrities/new - - ms - -

...there was an error by retrieving.. CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "new" at path "_id" for model "Celeb"
at model.Query.exec (/mnt/c/Users/carlo/documents/ironhack/labs/lab-mongoose-movies/starter-code/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4408:21)"

from what I understand, the problem lies in this route

```
router.get('/celebrities/:id', (req, res) => {
    const celebId = req.params.id
    console.log(celebId)
    Celeb.findById(celebId)

        .then(OneCeleb => {
            console.log(OneCeleb)
            res.render('celebrities/show', { OneCeleb })
        })

        .catch(error => console.log('there was an error by retrieving..', error))
})
```

but I have no clue why or where the error is, or why it is trying to look for an Id of new, is it the handlebars helpers?.

Comment: Instead of “/new” at the end of your URL, make it “/0”. The route param Id is always expected to be a number. I’m not sure if that messes with Celeb.findById at all but you just need to return a new instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the path `/celebrities/new` matches the pattern `/celebrities/:id`.

When you make a GET request to the path `/celebrities/new`, Express looks through all of the registered routes, in order, trying to find a match. When Express finds the registered route, `/celebrities/:id` it considers this a match because the request path matches the pattern - it starts with "/celebrities/" and is followed by an arbitrary string value which it interprets as the `id` param ("new").

Express will never serve the `/celebrities/new` GET route because `/celebrities/:id` will always be the first match.

In order to have Express find the `/celebrities/new` route, it must be registered *before* the `/celebrities/:id` route. You literally just need to move the `router.get('/celebrities/new'...` code *above* the `router.get('/celebrities/:id',...` code.

Comment: ooo God,thank you! it works!, so what would be the best practice when routing in express?

Comment: This isn't really specific to _routing in Express_. In any case where you are looping through a list in order to find a match, you would want to put values with wildcards after those without. ie., if you wanted to include a catch-all path (`/*`), you would need to register it last or it would catch _every_ request (of the same HTTP method).